# What is the most penalty kicks missed by a football team in one game?

Tags: football, trivia, history, penalty-shot

In week 28 of 2016-17 Premier league, Bournemouth missed 2 penalty kicks against West Ham and still managed to win the game. It had been a long time since I had seen that happen - excluding penalty kicks to decide a game in the knockout stage of a championship. I'm wondering, **what's the most penalty shots missed by a team in one game?**

To keep things simple, please restrict responses to only the top European leagues, the UEFA Champions League, and international games.

Comment: Mind you, there were heavy shouts for a third penalty for Bournemouth in the second half as well :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it's the team record, but [Martin Palermo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mart%C3%ADn_Palermo) (in)famously missed three penalties for Argentina in a Copa America game against Colombia in 1999.

Here is the [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53475jUreDU) of the incident.

There's detailed information for penalty shootouts at [rsssf.com](http://www.rsssf.com/miscellaneous/penalties.html).

Answer (score 4):

Here's another interesting one:

> In 1989, referee Kelvin Morton awarded five penalties in a Crystal
>   Palace v Brighton game, a Football League record. Palace were awarded
>   four of the penalties, missed three but still won 2-1.

[Source from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M23_derby#1980s)

Here is the [YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfdyE7b5bfQ&t=1s) of match highlights.

P.S: a tricky google search like *missed 4 penalties* or *missed 5 penalties* doesn't give relevant results, so I start to believe that 3 missed penalties by a team during a single game are indeed the most in the professional football.